# Why does Firefox throw on JSON parse error here?

Tags: javascript, json, firefox

Consider the following example.

```
<script>
var dirstruct=JSON.parse('{"Foo":{"Bar.txt":"\n"},"Blahblah.txt":"FooBar\n"}');
</script>
```

I have put the JSON inside the single quotes through the [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/), but when this file is loaded in Firefox, I get the following error.

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: bad control character in string literal at line 1 column 20 of the JSON data
```

What is the cause of this error and how can I correct it?

Comment: Escape backslashes [`JSON.parse('{"Foo":{"Bar.txt":"\\n"},"Blahblah.txt":"FooBar\\n"}')`](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/4zo8Lybk/)

Comment: @Tushar, Ugh, I was generating this in PHP and forgot there's a second layer of quoting on the JS side. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the error is that `"\n"` is interpreted as the literal newline character:

```
{"Foo":{"Bar.txt":"
"},"Blahblah.txt":"FooBar
"}
```

and this is an invalid JSON. You should esape `\n` with backslash:

```
var dirstruct=JSON.parse('{"Foo":{"Bar.txt":"\\n"},"Blahblah.txt":"FooBar\\n"}');
```

Answer (score 1):

Ruslan's answer highlighted the problem, but the solution he suggested was not the one I actually used, due to the fact that I was generating the `\n`'s from server-side code which didn't know the client had this problem.

The solution I actually used was [`String.raw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw) since that meant the server-side JSON generator could simply generate syntactically correct JSON without being concerned about it being re-interpreted by the Javascript String interpreter before being passed to the JSON parser.

```
<script>
var dirstruct=JSON.parse(String.raw`{"Foo":{"Bar.txt":"\n"},"Blahblah.txt":"FooBar\n"}`);
</script>
```

Sometimes the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) can be too simple.